# How to show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}$ is real-analytic?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a ∈ \Bbb R$, and define $f : \Bbb R \backslash \{a\} → \Bbb R$ by $f(x) = 1/(x − a)$. Show that f is real-analytic.

I can tell that f(x) is comparible to the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}$ where if $g:= \Bbb R \backslash \{1\} \to \Bbb R$, $g(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}$, the function $g(x)$ is real-analytic

however I can't quite find the relationship between them and is struggling with the proof. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c \neq a$. $\frac 1 {x-a} =\frac 1 {c-a} \frac 1 {1+\frac {x-c} {c-a}}$ and you can use the expansion $\frac 1 {1+y}=\sum (-1)^{n}y^{n}$ for $|y| <1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \ne 0$ we have $\frac{1}{x-a}= -\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\left (1- \frac x a \right )}=-\frac{1}{a} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{a^n} =-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{a^{n+1}}$ for $|x|<|a|.$

Comment: This gives analyticity at $0$.